# python random function generating same values for two different instances

Tags: python, random

So for this code I am writing I am attempting to generate a set of three random cards each for three different players one of which is human and two are simulated. for this I am using this code.

```
def shuffle_p1():
    p_1_human_card_1=random.randint(1,3)
    p_1_human_card_2=random.randint(1,3)
    p_1_human_card_3=random.randint(1,3)
    p_1_human_cards=[p_1_human_card_1,p_1_human_card_2,p_1_human_card_3]

    return (p_1_human_cards)


def shuffle_p2():
    p_2_ai_card_1=random.randint(1,3)
    p_2_ai_card_2=random.randint(1,3)
    p_2_ai_card_3=random.randint(1,3)
    p_2_ai_cards=[p_2_ai_card_1,p_2_ai_card_2,p_2_ai_card_3]

    return (p_1_human_cards)


def shuffle_p3():
    p_3_ai_card_1=random.randint(1,3)
    p_3_ai_card_2=random.randint(1,3)
    p_3_ai_card_3=random.randint(1,3)
    p_3_ai_cards=[p_3_ai_card_1,p_3_ai_card_2,p_3_ai_card_3]

    return (p_1_human_cards)

p_1_human_cards=shuffle_p1()
p_2_ai_cards=shuffle_p2()
p_3_ai_cards=shuffle_p3()
```

this generates the three sets but player 1 and player 2 have the exact same cards every time. i even put a different set of code

```
def card_auth_p1():
    while p_1_human_cards[0]==p_1_human_cards[1] or p_1_human_cards[0]==p_1_human_cards[2]:
        p_1_human_cards[0]=random.randint(1,3)
    while p_1_human_cards[1]==p_1_human_cards[0] or p_1_human_cards[1]==p_1_human_cards[2]:
        p_1_human_cards[1]=random.randint(1,3)

def card_auth_p2():
    while p_2_ai_cards[0]==p_2_ai_cards[1] or p_2_ai_cards[0]==p_2_ai_cards[2]:
        p_2_ai_cards[0]=random.randint(1,3)
    while p_2_ai_cards[1]==p_2_ai_cards[0] or p_2_ai_cards[1]==p_2_ai_cards[2]:
        p_2_ai_cards[1]=random.randint(1,3)

def card_auth_p3():
    while p_3_ai_cards[0]==p_3_ai_cards[1] or p_3_ai_cards[0]==p_3_ai_cards[2]:
        p_3_ai_cards[0]=random.randint(1,3)
    while p_3_ai_cards[1]==p_3_ai_cards[0] or p_3_ai_cards[1]==p_3_ai_cards[2]:
        p_3_ai_cards[1]=random.randint(1,3)
```

and also

```
if p_1_human_cards == p_2_ai_cards or p_1_human_cards == p_3_ai_cards:
    p_1_human_cards=shuffle_p1()

if p_2_ai_cards == p_1_human_cards or p_2_ai_cards == p_3_ai_cards:
    p_2_ai_cards=shuffle_p2()

if p_3_ai_cards == p_1_human_cards or p_2_ai_cards == p_3_ai_cards:
    p_3_ai_cards=shuffle_p3()
```

to make sure that they were not all the same but printing the three lists reveals that player 1 and 2 are still the same. in addition even after a fourth block of code of random trading in between the three sets using this code

```
def card_trade():
    print('Round 1')
    p_1_choice=int(input('pick the card you want to take from player 2'))
    while p_1_choice<1 or p_1_choice>3:
        print('pick between 1 and 3')
        p_1_choice=int(input('pick the card you want to take from player 2'))

    if p_1_choice==1:
       p_1_extra_card=p_2_ai_cards[0]
       p_2_ai_cards.remove(p_2_ai_cards[0])

    elif p_1_choice==2:
       p_1_extra_card=p_2_ai_cards[1]
       p_2_ai_cards.remove(p_2_ai_cards[1])

    elif p_1_choice==3:
       p_1_extra_card=p_2_ai_cards[2]
       p_2_ai_cards.remove(p_2_ai_cards[2])

    p_1_human_cards.append(p_1_extra_card)

    p_2_choice=random.randint(1,3)

    print('AI decided to take',p_2_choice,'from player 3')
    if p_2_choice==1:
       p_2_extra_card=p_3_ai_cards[0]
       p_3_ai_cards.remove(p_3_ai_cards[0])

    elif p_2_choice==2:
       p_2_extra_card=p_3_ai_cards[1]
       p_3_ai_cards.remove(p_3_ai_cards[1])

    elif p_2_choice==3:
       p_2_extra_card=p_3_ai_cards[2]
       p_3_ai_cards.remove(p_3_ai_cards[2])

    p_2_ai_cards.append(p_2_extra_card)

    p_3_choice=random.randint(1,4)

    print('AI decided to take',p_3_choice,'from player 1')
    if p_3_choice==1:
       p_3_extra_card=p_1_human_cards[0]
       p_1_human_cards.remove(p_1_human_cards[0])

    elif p_3_choice==2:
       p_3_extra_card=p_1_human_cards[1]
       p_1_human_cards.remove(p_1_human_cards[1])

    elif p_3_choice==3:
       p_3_extra_card=p_1_human_cards[2]
       p_1_human_cards.remove(p_1_human_cards[2])

    elif p_3_choice==3:
       p_3_extra_card=p_1_human_cards[3]
       p_1_human_cards.remove(p_1_human_cards[33])

    p_3_ai_cards.append(p_3_extra_card)
```

the first two players always end up exactly the same. I cannot seem to figure out why they seem to never change and would appreciate any insight to help fix this problem.

another thing to note sometimes during card trade() when the human player picks 3 as their choice the computer can throw an error but it does this very inconsistently so i cannot pinpoint the origin of that error either.

Comment: Why does `shuffle_p2` return `(p_1_human_cards)`?

Comment: This happens to all of us.  Sometimes you've stared at the same code for so long, you don't see the obvious.

Comment: but as for the error at the end after re running it with the changes to shuffle_p2 and 3 it still gives this error UnboundLocalError: local variable 'p_3_extra_card' referenced before assignment. any more insight to help with this please?

Comment: @MustafaShahzad: You test `elif p_3_choice==3:` twice, instead of testing `elif p_3_choice==4:` (or just using `else:` which would make sense here); if a `4` comes up, you never assign `p_3_extra_card`, thus the error.

Comment: @ShadowRanger thank you for pointing that out. I think I have been working on this for too long today if these are the types of mistakes that I am making. hopefully tomorrow ill be able to polish this off without making anymore mistakes.

Comment: Your three functions do precisely the same thing. You do not need three of them. One is enough.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that you got copying the previous blocks of codes and the `return` part stayed the same. :) Try to [code DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) as possible.
Also you can do it like this:

```
import random
def shuffle_p1():
    p_1_human_cards=[random.randint(1,3) for _ in range(3)]
    return p_1_human_cards

def shuffle_p2():
    p_2_ai_cards=[random.randint(1,3) for _ in range(3)]
    return p_2_ai_cards

def shuffle_p3():
    p_3_ai_cards=[random.randint(1,3) for _ in range(3)]
    return p_3_ai_cards
```

Comment: It is the same function written three times.

Comment: yeah i will admit that i copied some of this stuff from a different file of code for the same task that i was working on this morning that got a bit too messy to clean up so i started over. but i will be taking your advice to heart and thank you sir.

Comment: @DYZ yeah that's not the best. Only a little clearer. Maybe you could suggest an edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Python 3.6+, you can also try secrets

```
try:
    import secrets as random
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    import random

# Use system resources for randomization
rnd = random.SystemRandom()

# Set available card options
AVAILABLE_CARDS = [1,2,3,]

# Set number of cards per hand.
NUMBER_OF_CARDS = 3

# Create a simple key-value collection.
players = dict(
    p_1_human_cards = None,
    p_2_ai_cards = None,
    p_3_ai_cards= None,
    )

# Define a shuffler() function.  Parameters are number of cards and available cards.
def shuffler(n_cards=NUMBER_OF_CARDS , available_cards = AVAILABLE_CARDS ):
    return tuple([rnd.choice(available_cards) for _ in range(n_cards)])

# Iterate through players to set each hand
for hand in players:
    players[hand] = shuffler()


# Print result
for player, hand in players.items():
    print(f"{player}: {hand}")
```

Output:

```
p_1_human_cards: (2, 1, 3)
p_2_ai_cards: (3, 2, 1)
p_3_ai_cards: (2, 3, 3)
```